# Get information from HTML by identifying tags

Tags: java, android, html-parsing

All- I have never done this sort of thing before and am very confused. I have spent hours on Google looking for some example code or any hints but whenever I try to work with the available code I always get errors and end up more confused than when I started. So enough self pity and excuses. Lets get to the question: I have an app the "screen scraps" a website, right now Google. I have got it so I can display the html in a text view:
[image]
My problem now is getting the information from this. All I want is the information in the title tag ("Google"). I have read about HTML parsing but was very confused when I read the information on TagSoup or others like that. Do I need those to do it or is there just some Java code I can write to pull out the title tag and make it into a string and than display it. If I do need an HTML parser, can someone give me some example code. I could not find any on their website. 
Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String page;
String display;
Document doc;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
    new AddStringTask().execute();      
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}    
class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {    
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
        ResponseHandler<String> resHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        try {
            page = httpClient.execute(httpGet, resHandler);             
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {           
    }       
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {  
        TextView google = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.google);         
        google.setText(page);       
    }       
}
}
```

Any sample code would be great because I need to see some examples. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jsoup: Java HTML Parser](http://jsoup.org/) should do the trick:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get();
String docTitle = doc.title();
```

Then pass `docTitle` to `google.setText()`

You can find more examples [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html).

Comment: What do I have to do to add Jsoup to my code. I have downloaded it. Do I need to add it as a library or what?

Comment: OK. I got that down. Next, where should I put your code snippet inside of my code?

Comment: It replaces all of your code inside of the doInBackground method. I Respectfully suggest that you brush up on your java skills before you go further.

Comment: I know. I got it now. Thanks for you help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16501/discussion-between-sean-w-and-androidcurious)